# [prestashop]: bad with html rendering

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i'm using smart to display a bloc of html code .

my problem is that it not interpret my html code.

there is my code

```
<dl class="accordion">
    {foreach $faqs as $allfaq}
        <dt><a href="">{$allfaq.question_post}</a></dt>
        <dd>
            {$allfaq.content|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        </dd>
    {/foreach}
</dl>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: try to remove the `'htmlall'` from the escape

Answer (score 1):

Add `nofilter` filter:

```
{$allfaq.content nofilter}
```